# Windows 10 Брандмауэр. Запретить все исходящие подключения с исключением пользователя

Tags: windows-10, firewall

В ОС находятся два пользователя: Администратор и обычный пользователь.

Цель: Заблокировать выход в интернет обычному пользователю.

Захожу в "Панель управления\Система и безопасность\Брандмауэр Защитника Windows" выбираю "Дополнительные параметры" далее "Правила для исходящих подключений".

Создаю новое правило с параметрами:
Для программы> Все программы > Блокировать подключение > Для всех профилей (Доменный, Частный, Публичный) > Имя > Готово.

Правило создано, доступ в интернет не работает на обеих учетных записях.

Захожу в свойства правила. Выбираю вкладку "Локальные субъекты" там находятся два чекбокса:

- Авторизованные пользователи (Разрешать подключения только от этих
  пользователей)
- Исключения (Пропускать это правило при подключении от
  этих пользователей)

Отмечаю второе и добавляю Администратора. После применения интернет доступен не только у Администратора. Но и у обычного пользователя.
Что не так?

Так же не работает и по первому чекбоксу.